# SQL Getting Date Range

Tags: sql, oracle, date, date-range

I need to aggregate costs to be displayed by date range per month. To illustrate please take a look at the following:

#### Sample Data

```
invoice_id     usage_date         cost
--------------------------------------
123            May 31, 2016         $4
150            June 01, 2016        $4
150            June 02, 2016        $4
150            June 03, 2016        $4
150            June 04, 2016        $5
150            June 05, 2016        $5
...
150            June 30, 2016        $5
240            July 01, 2016        $8
```

Taking into account the data above, I want to get

#### Desired Result

```
range                   total
-----------------------------
June 01-03, 2016          $12
June 04-30, 2016         $135
```

As you'll notice I want to group them and add those with the same `cost` but display the dates as start to end. But this has to be done for each month only. In this particular case, let's say `May 31, 2016` incurred a cost of `$4`, it wouldn't be included even though it has the same cost with the next day (June 01) because they're from different months.

I feel like I need to provide more information but I'm not sure what you guys still need so just comment what you want me to add.

#### EDIT

I don't know if this matters but let me just add a query I used to generate the **sample data** I provided above.

#### Sample Data - SQL

```
SELECT id.invoice_id, di.usage_date, SUM(di.item_cost) AS cost
FROM detail_items di
LEFT JOIN invoice_details id
ON id.id = di.detail_id
WHERE di.group_id = 123456
GROUP BY id.invoice_id, di.usage_date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate by year, month and cost and get the min and max dates for a given cost. Then multiply the cost with the total rows in a given month to get the total.

```
select to_char(mindt,'mm/dd/yyyy')||'-'||to_char(maxdt,'mm/dd/yyyy') daterange,
cnt*cost total
from (
select 
cost, min(usage_date) mindt, max(usage_date) maxdt, count(*) cnt,
to_char(usage_date,'mm') usg_mth,to_char(usage_date,'yyyy') usg_yr
from tablename
group by to_char(usage_date,'mm'),to_char(usage_date,'yyyy'),cost
) t
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this would work but I have no clue how to incorporate your answer to the query I used to generate my sample data. I've added some info in the question if it helps.

Comment: Also, I need to do this inside a software that is buggy with subqueries. This might work with regular SQL clients like PL/SQL but I doubt subqueries will work with the software I use. If you have another approach where we can avoid subqueries I would prefer that. But don't worry about it too much.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio - your question says Oracle -- I don't believe Oracle has bugs with processing sub-queries.  Are you using some other platform?

Comment: @Hogan The software uses Oracle but they implemented it differently I think. I believe the software pre-parses my queries before running it against Oracle.

Comment: If the issue with subqueries is too much just ignore it. I just thought I'd mention it in case there's a solution available where I won't need to use subqueries. But I'd settle with whatever works. I'll just have to forward the concern with the software vendor.

Comment: @vkp My concern with this is that the `cnt` is wrong. I would see a value of 56 in this column which is weird since a month can only have up to 31 days.

Comment: are you sure there is only one row per date?

Comment: @vkp Yes. I was able to fix it by adding the invoice_id in the group by. It's ok now. Thanks a lot!